# PHP PDO как сделать чтобы выполнение скрипта не прекратилось после ошибки если сервер базы данных не работает?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

Пишу API которое возвращает JSON. И мне нужно чтобы это API всегда возвращало результат не зависимо ответил ли сервер БД, потому что часть информации хранится в сессии и других файлах, и если сервер БД не доступен то будет просто флаг в возвращённом JSON.
Конфигурация софта: PHP 7.3, mariadb 10.3.24, CentOs 7 x64
У меня же происходит следующее:

```
self::$pdo = new PDO(("mysql:host=" . self::$mysqlhost . ";dbname=" . self::$mysqldb),self::$mysqluser,self::$mysqlpassword,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING,PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"));
```

Если остановить сервер mariadb то появляется такая ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /var/www/sitename/dir/scriptname.php:28 
Stack trace: 
    #0 /var/www/sitaname/dir/scriptname.php(28): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'user', 'password', Array)
    #1 /var/www/sitename/dir/scriptname.php(43): myPDO::init()
    #2 /var/www/sitaname/dir/scriptname.php(104): myPDO::get()
    #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/sitename/dir/scriptname.php on line 28
```

Это при расширенном выводе ошибок

```
ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
```

Причём при расширенном выводе ошибок, указанный текст ошибки появляется не зависимо обернул ли я строчку с установкой соединения с базой через PDO в try catch или нет. И даже если я помещаю в catch строчку `echo "Ошибка при установке соединения с базой данных";` всё равно эта строчка не появляется. То есть выполнение скрипта почему-то прекращается сразу после установки соединения выводом указанной ошибки.

В поисковиках была информация о том что нужно использовать режим исключений PDO - `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`, как Вы можете видеть из кода я его установил. Написано что при таком режиме доступна информация по ошибке, но работа скрипта не должна прерваться, но в описанном случаи она всё равно почему-то прерывается и блок catch всё равно не выполняется.

Как просто отловить ситуацию о отсутствии соединения с базой без прерывания работы скрипта?

Добавляю блок try - catch по просьбе в комментариях:

```
  public static function init() {
    if (self::$pdo === false) {
      try {
        self::$pdo = new PDO(("mysql:host=" . self::$mysqlhost . ";dbname=" . self::$mysqldb),self::$mysqluser,self::$mysqlpassword,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"));//ещё вот это в массив пробовал PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING
        return true;
      } catch(PDOExeception $e) {
        echo "Не удалось соединиться с базой данных";
        return false;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

**Опечатка в слове PDOExeception в коде выше оставлена умышленно. Если кто будет использовать код, обязательно исправьте ошибку!**

Comment: Оберните ваш код в `try/catch` конструкцию и обрабатывайте исключения. Подробнее [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: Так я же написал, что не помогает try catch. Я написал что в catch встявляю тестовый echo, но это сообщение не появляется, то есть содержание catch не выполняется. Почему то сразу после строчки с коннектом по PDO появляется сообщение и на этом выполнение останавливается.

Comment: @sandimagox, дополните ваш вопрос информацией о заданных параметрах у catch()

Comment: } catch(PDOExeception $e) {echo "Ошибка соединения с базой!";return false;} вот всё что там написано. А return false; это потому что try внутри метода класса и мне нужно чтобы он вернул false при ошибке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очепятка в исключении. У вас "PDOEx**e**ception", а нужно: "PDOException"

Comment: Да!!! Всё в этом вдимо дело и было. Я поправил и сразу стал блок catch выполняться и после него продолжается выполнение скрипта как мне и надо. А я ранее с PDO работал, помню же что можно. Начал думать сначала на версию PHP 7.3, оказалось вот какая ошибка может быть. Благодарю!

Comment: В этом же вопросе спрошу. А обязательно ли при INSERT указывать все поля таблицы базы данных? Если я любое кроме автоинкрементируемого поля(его можно не указывать) не вставлю в запрос - то он не проходит. Почему так? Причем даже если я указал у полей базы данных значение по умолчанию.

Comment: @sandimagox, нет, не обязательно. Только нужно в указывать перед `VALUES` именно те поля и в таком порядке как вставляете. Т.е. если в таблице есть поля field1-field4, то вставка только field3 и field2 будет такой: `INSERT table(field3, field2) VALUES ('value3', 'value2')`

Comment: Так и делал, может быть я в вторых скобках значения не стёр, но несколько же раз пробовал. Ок. Благодарю, будет время посвободнее потестирую. А касаемо значения полей по умолчанию они нужны или нет? mysqli без них перестало работать на INSERT после обновления mariadb.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, значение по умолчанию не обязательно. Хочу заметить, что коментарии не предназначены для обсуждения не по теме начального вопроса, поэтому если у вас есть ещё вопросы, то можете создать новый или поискать информацию сами

Comment: Благодарю Вас за замечание, понял. Я просто не знал что так нельзя. Если что создам новый вопрос.